# hide the bash input in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, applescript

I'm executing a bash command from AppleScript but the script is quite ugly and I am only interested to see the output in a terminal.

Example:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "pwd"
end tell
```

Terminal(I want to hide pwd):

```
pwd 
/Users/jdoe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `clear` (or `tput clear` or `printf \\ec`), the old contents are shown if you scroll up:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script " clear; pwd"
    activate
end tell
```

This can have a noticeable delay if System Events is not running:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script " osascript -e 'tell app \"system events\" to keystroke \"k\" using command down'; pwd"
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

The command is `do shell script "pwd"`, and it did show only the output when I ran it in Script Editor or via `osascript test.scpt` in a Terminal.

Comment: I've updated my example, instead of "pwd" there is an interactive script and "do script" executes it through the terminal.

Comment: Why do you go to the trouble of starting a Terminal instead of simply running `do shell script`?

Comment: Because I want a user to interact with it in a terminal, do shell script would execute it in the background.